# How to define “up” and “down” trends in R?

Tags: r, regression

How it's possible to define "up" and "down" trends in this data by using R functions and models. The value could be negative for the "down" trend [-1, 0), and positive for the "up" trend (0, 1]. I assume that for this test trend should be "down".

```
x <- c(1:8)  
y <- c(99, 104, 108, 100, 86, 64, 35, 15)

plot(x, y)
lines(x, y)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Without a specification of "trend" it is not possible to answer your question. If you are looking for Pearson's correlation coefficient, use `cor(x, y)`.

Answer (score 3):

A [trend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trend) in a [sequence of random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process) does not have a single mathematical or computational definition, however you may be interested in [linear trend estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_trend_estimation).

At a minimum:

- Examine and interpret [plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plot_(graphics)) of your data
- [Select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection), [fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_statistics), and evaluate your model of the "trend"
- Interpret the model in the context of your use case

#### Edit

I plotted your example data, and observed the following:
[image]

Which is clearly a non-linear and (mostly?) concave pattern. I do not recommend a simple linear equation nor Pearson's product-moment correlation coefficient for this case.